# [here-api]REST API to find all streets that cross a line

Tags: rest, here-api

I have a line defined by the locations of its 2 ends. Is there a Here REST API call that retrieves all the streets/roads that cross this line?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about your use case?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what to elaborate on?
A line?
Street/Road?
Cross?
Cross is meant here as a synonym for intersect.

Let me know if my question is still unclear.

Comment: I mean what did you tried yet with API and where are you facing issues, please let me know by updating your question.